# Factorial of a matrix elementwise with Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vectorization, factorial

I'd like to know how to calculate the factorial of a matrix elementwise. For example,

```
import numpy as np
mat = np.array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])

np.the_function_i_want(mat)
```

would give a matrix `mat2` such that `mat2[i,j] = mat[i,j]!`. I've tried something like

```
np.fromfunction(lambda i,j: np.math.factorial(mat[i,j]))
```

but it passes the entire matrix as argument for `np.math.factorial`. I've also tried to use `scipy.vectorize` but for matrices larger than 10x10 I get an error. This is the code I wrote:

```
import scipy as sp
javi = sp.fromfunction(lambda i,j: i+j, (15,15))
fact = sp.vectorize(sp.math.factorial)
fact(javi)

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Such an integer number would be greater than 2e9, so I don't understand what this means.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a [`factorial`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.factorial.html#scipy.special.factorial) function in `scipy.special` which allows element-wise computations on arrays:

```
>>> from scipy.special import factorial
>>> factorial(mat)
array([[  1.,   2.,   6.],
       [  2.,   6.,  24.]])
```

The function returns an array of float values and so can compute "larger" factorials up to the accuracy floating point numbers allow:

```
>>> factorial(15)
array(1307674368000.0)
```

You may need to adjust the print precision of NumPy arrays if you want to avoid the number being displayed in scientific notation.

---

Regarding `scipy.vectorize`: the `OverflowError` implies that the result of some of the calculations are too big to be stored as integers (normally `int32` or `int64`).

If you want to vectorize `sp.math.factorial` and want arbitrarily large integers, you'll need to specify that the function return an output array with the `'object'` datatype. For instance:

```
fact = sp.vectorize(sp.math.factorial, otypes='O')
```

Specifying the `'object'` type allows Python integers to be returned by `fact`. These are not limited in size and so you can calculate factorials as large as your computer's memory will permit. Be aware that arrays of this type lose some of the speed and efficiency benefits which regular NumPy arrays have.

Comment: For scipy >= 1.0.0 `factorial` from `scipy.misc` is deprecated. One has to use `scipy.special.factorial` instead.